# Parse-server + mongoDB - high server overload

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

We are using parse-server + mongoDB on the own server for the mobile game backend. There are about 200K users with ~2k connected at the same time. The "_Session" collection is about 1 million records and continues to grow.

Servers CPUs are constantly loaded on 100% each.
In the MongoDB logs I can see 95% records like:

> 2017-05-11T16:25:24.738+0300 I COMMAND  [conn1] command appdb1._Session command: find { find: "_Session", filter: { _session_token: "r:9eaba843dc3f8b482dbc76009f94c18a" }, sort: {}, projection: {}, limit: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1015131 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:7930 nreturned:1 resle
>   n:428 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 15862 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 7931 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 7931 } } } protocol:op_query 556ms

I've created index for the _Session collection, 
db.getCollection("_Session").getIndexes()
[

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "appdb1._Session"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "sessionToken" : 1
    },
    "name" : "sessionToken_1",
    "ns" : "appdb1._Session",
    "background" : true
}
```

]

but, as I understand, it is not used, and DB performs full collection scan every time when it searches for a record.

So server кesponds with great delays, please, help with this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I see in logs, your query on field  _session_token and you have indexed sessionToken.. can you check?

Comment: O, I think parse-server makes own renaming of fields at display, I'll try to create index for the _session_token field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating index on key _session_token in background:

```
db.yourCollection.ensureIndex({ "_session_token":1}, {background:true})
```

This will avoid collection scan for the query with key  `_session_token`.

Comment: I have donee: db.getCollection("_Session").createIndex({_session_token:1}, { background: true }).

Comment: did this index help?

Comment: After this strings in log changed to: 2017-05-12T09:43:05.932+0300 I COMMAND  [conn1] command appdb1._Session command: find { find: "_Session", filter: {}, sort: { _updated_at: -1, _created_at: -1 }, projection: {}, limit: 200 } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:63685935618 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1031857 hasSortStage:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYie
lds:8062 nreturned:101 reslen:31250 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 16126 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 8063 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 8063 } } } protocol:op_query 3706ms

Comment: this looks like another query? CPU usage is still high?

Comment: CPU usage become about 10-20%! Thank you!